# How to display two videos simultaneously with surface view

Tags: android

I am a beginner in android development.
I was trying to display a video with surface view using media codec for which i am successful.
Now I want to add one more video at run time which has to be displayed or hidden as per the wish of the user or to switch between the two.
Can I have some suggestions for the same...

Thanks......

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: As a first step I was trying to display the two videos simultaneously. I tried adding 1 more surface at run time which i could do but was not able to display video on it.    Thanks for response......

Comment: I tried with fragments but came to know that it can not be hidden at run time. So trying to get another possibility of doing it........

Comment: plz include your code... So that any one can answer for your query..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public class CustomPictureActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    VideoView vd1,vd2;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        vd1=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.v1);
        vd2=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.v2);
        vd1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("/mnt/sdcard/file.mp4"));
        vd1.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        vd1.requestFocus();
        vd1.start();

        vd2.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("/mnt/sdcard/android.mp4"));
        vd2.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        vd2.requestFocus();
        vd2.start();
    }
}
```

Your xml code should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<VideoView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" 
    android:id="@+id/v1"/>

<VideoView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" 
    android:id="@+id/v2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

May this will help you.